# How to get the return of a created object in Mongoose with express api

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my express api, using mongoose, i create a new user on api using User.create. How i can get the return of the created object to include on the response?

My method to create a object is:

```
async store (req, res) {
const { name, lastName, email, password } = req.body

if (await User.findOne({ email })) {
  return res.status(400).json({ error: 'User already exists' })
}

try {
  await User.create({
    name,
    lastName,
    email,
    password,
    role: 'USER_ROLE'
  })

  res.status(201).json({
    ok: true,
    message: 'User created'
  })
} catch (e) {
  res.status(500).json({
    ok: false,
    message: 'Failed to create User'
  })
}
```

}

I want to return the user created on the res, like:

```
 res.status(201).json({
    ok: true,
    message: 'User created',
    user: user

  })
```

Answer (score 11):

```
async store(req, res) {
  const { name, lastName, email, password } = req.body

  if (await User.findOne({ email })) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'User already exists' })
  }

  try {
    let user = await User.create({
      name,
      lastName,
      email,
      password,
      role: 'USER_ROLE'
    })
    user = user.toJson();
    delete user.password;
    delete user.role;
    res.status(201).json({
      ok: true,
      user: user,
      message: 'User created'
    })
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({
      ok: false,
      message: 'Failed to create User'
    })
  }
}
```

You can covert mongoose object to JSON using

```
user.toJson()
```

Then you can delete the fields that you don't want to send into the response.

```
delete user.password;
```

Comment: This way works like expected. But in this case, how i can remove some fields from the returned object? I want to remove the password and the role from  the return. Its possible? thanks

Comment: Where you defined your schema, you can add

`schema.set('toJSON', { transform: (document, returnedObject) => { delete user.password; delete user.role; } })`

This is basically overriding the output of the `toJSON` method. More info here: https://fullstackopen.com/en/part4/user_administration#mongoose-schema-for-users